# Arranging numbers in a file using C

Tags: c, file

I need to take the numbers listed in the two files "numbers1.txt" and "numbers2.txt" (where the numbers are listed in ascending order) and move them to a file named "output.txt" where they are arranged in ascending order.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void appendToOutput(FILE *numFile1, FILE *numFile2, FILE *outputFile)
{
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;

do {
    fscanf(numFile1, "%d", &num1);
    fscanf(numFile2, "%d", &num2);
    while ((num1 < num2) && !feof(numFile1))
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n", num1);
        fscanf(numFile1, "%d", &num1);
    }
    while ((num2 < num1) && !feof(numFile2))
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n", num2);
        fscanf(numFile2, "%d", &num2);
    }
    if (num1 == num2)
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n%d\n", num1, num2);
    }
} while (!feof(numFile1) || !feof(numFile2));

return;
}
```

my files look like the following:

numbers1.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

numbers2.txt:

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
24
```

The issue I am having is that the output file ends up looking like this:
output.txt

```
1
2
2
3
4
4
5
6
6
7
8
8
9
10
10
11
12
12
```

So my issue is that the program is not continuing to read/write numbers from numbers2.txt even though it has not yet hit the end of it's file. I've looked through it and I can't seem to find out why it's stopping, so help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Please see Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2173917)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? Hint: After the end of `numFile1`, your second while loop is `while (14 < 12 && !feof()){}`.

Comment: @Ani The fix isn't that simple.  That will prevent premature exit, but it will attempt to read past EOF on the shorter file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the current code

1. Initialization of the 2 numbers should be performed before the main loop
2. Use of `feof()` here
3. Test of strict `<` insteaf of `<=` (could lock your algo)
4. Keep reading a file if the other one becomes empty

Regarding 2., `fscanf` returns a number `>0` if it could read the number, so you can test this instead of checking `feof` (that says that EOF (a stop condition) happened before, and this might trigger one more unwanted iteration).

Suggested fixed code:

```
int read1 = fscanf(numFile1, "%d", &num1);
int read2 = fscanf(numFile2, "%d", &num2);

while (read1 > 0 || read2 > 0) {
    while (read1 > 0 && (read2<=0 || num1 <= num2))
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n", num1);
        read1 = fscanf(numFile1, "%d", &num1);
    }
    while (read2 > 0 && (read1<=0 || num2 <= num1))
    {
        fprintf(outputFile, "%d\n", num2);
        read2 = fscanf(numFile2, "%d", &num2);
    }
}
```

Further explanations

- `readX<=0 || numY <= numX` addresses `4.`
- `readX = fscanf(...)` addresses`2.`

Comment: When I tried to use `fscanf`'s return values the program didn't put anything into the output file. It only started working once I put in the `feof()`

Comment: This is because the excerpt above was to show the output in the console. The answer has been edited to write results into `outputFile`.